# Подсчет уникальных чисел в массиве

Tags: java, массивы

Программа должна подсчитывать уникальные чисел в массиве, например

```
input:
{1, 1, 3, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 6}

output:
2
```

Код:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] znamka = {1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 2, 3, 1, 5};
    System.out.println(Diff(znamka));
}

public static int Diff(int[] znamka){
        ArrayList<Integer> ArrUnique = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        int values=0;
        for (int num : znamka) {
            if (!ArrUnique.contains(num)) ArrUnique.add(num);
        }
        values = ArrUnique.size();
        if (values == 1) values = 0;
        return values;
    }
```

Пожалуйста подскажите, можно ли написать без `ArrayList`, если да, то как?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32444901/9908035

Comment: Вы хотя бы начните программу писать.

Comment: Учебные задания допустимы в качестве вопросов только при условии, что вы пытались решить их самостоятельно перед тем, как задать вопрос. Пожалуйста, отредактируйте вопрос и укажите, что именно вызвало у вас трудности при решении задачи. Например, приведите код, который вы написали, пытаясь решить задачу.

Answer (score 0):

Не совсем понял вопроса... вопрос можно трактовать двояко.
В первом случае все просто:
Arrays.stream(znamka).distinct().count();

Во втором случае любой лист - плохое решение. 
В листе любой поиск производится обычной итерацией. это медленно. 
попробуйте так. в этом случае в коллекции не просто информация о количестве уникальных элементов, а информация о количестве повторений всех элементов.

final Map  countMap = new HashMap<>();
Arrays.stream(znamka).forEach(value -> countMap.put(value, ((countMap.get(value)==null)?1:countMap.get(value)+1)));
long count = countMap.keySet().stream().filter(t -> countMap.get(t)==1).count();